# Displaying Images in Gallery and sharing them

Tags: android, android-intent

My application is capable of capturing images and saving them (in the public `Pictures` directory, retrieved by `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`.

Now, I want to be able to display those images in the system's gallery application. In order to achieve that, I create an Intent like this (`filePath` is a String containing the image's path):

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent();
viewIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath));
viewIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(viewIntent, null));
```

Displaying an image this way works perfectly fine, but the gallery's `Share` functionality doesn't seem to work: 
When I press the `Share`-button, I get to choose the app I want to share to; but once I select it, nothing happens, as if the target application does not receive any data.

Is there any explanation why this behaviour occurs and how it can be fixed?

Edit: I used [Intent Intercept](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept) to capture the Intent created by the Gallery/Photos app:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you see any errors in logcat?

Comment: make your app control the "share-to" and then inspect the uri passed in. If the pattern of the uri is just like the Gallery app, then it should work   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery.git/+/android-5.1.1_r14/src/com/android/camera/GalleryPicker.java?autodive=0%2F  #179 may help with the intents

Comment: No, sadly logcat does not provide any helpful error messages. Also, I added two images to the question showing the intent created by the Photos app.